# Filter by card title brings only the text not the entire card with all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, function, search

I want to filter cards along with their contents (the entire box to show) including title texts and copy button.

For example, when I search for box1 the text "box1" alone is filtered. I want to get the entire card when searched with the title name say "box1".

I coded to filter text inside ".phc-home-hashtags" where all cards live. But it gets only that text not entire card. I'm a beginner in jquery. I copied code and tested from jquery website but I'm not getting the desired results.

Here is the code.

```js
//finding and copying tags
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.phc-hashtags-box-button', function () {
  var copy = $(this).parents('.phc-hashtags-box').find('.phc-hashtags-box-tags').html();
  console.log(copy);
  var $temp = $('<input>');
  $('body').append($temp);
  $temp.val(copy).select();
  console.log($temp);
  document.execCommand('copy');
  $temp.remove();
    });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#phc-home-search-bar").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".phc-home-hashtags *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});


//toast message
function launch_toast() {
    var x = document.getElementById("phc-toast")
    x.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 5000);
}

//scroll to top 
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 150) {        // If page is scrolled more than 50px
        $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(400);    // Fade in the arrow
    } else {
        $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(400);   // Else fade out the arrow
    }
});
$('#return-to-top').click(function() {      // When arrow is clicked
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop : 0                       // Scroll to top of body
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
/***1. css reset***/
body{
 font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 margin:0;
 line-height:1.6;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 font-weight: 400;
}

/***2. container***/
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}

/***3. header***/
header{
 background-color: #fff;
 height: 80px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 1px #d8d8d8;
}
.phc-brand{
 float: left;
}
.phc-brand-logo{
 width: 40px;
 margin: 20px 0px;
}
.phc-navigation{
 float: right;
 line-height: 40px;
}
.phc-navigation-item{
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
 color: #888;
 margin-right: 40px;
}
.phc-navigation-item:last-of-type{
 margin-right: 0;
}
.phc-navigation-item a{
 color: #888;
 text-decoration: none;
}
/***4. home-intro***/
.phc-home-fold-content{
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 padding: 50px 0px 20px;
}

.phc-home-intro{
 text-align: center;
}
.phc-home-intro-title{
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.phc-brand-home-intro{
 width: 24px;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
.phc-home-search-container{
 width: 580px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
#phc-home-search-bar{
 width: 100%;
 outline: none;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
 box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
 height: 50px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 5px 38px;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #888;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ddd;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
#phc-home-search-bar:focus{
 color: #666;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0px #aaa;
}
.phc-home-search-icon{
 padding: 12px;
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 top: -48px;
 right: 0px;
 opacity: 0.4;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
 .phc-home-intro-title{
  line-height: 1.2;
 }
 .phc-home-search-container{
  width: 100%;
 }
}
.phc-home-search-hashtag{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 top: -43px;
 left: 15px;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #666;
}
.phc-home-intro-tip{
 color: #999;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}


/***hashtags-box-tags***/
.phc-home-hashtags{
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 padding: 40px 0px;
}
.phc-home-hashtags-section{
 display: inline-block;
}
.phc-home-hashtags-section-title{
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #3f51b5;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 5px 12px;
 display: table-cell;
}
.phc-home-hashtags-section-content{
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom:15px;
}
.phc-hashtags-box{
 display:inline-block;
 width: 30.5%;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-right: 1.3%;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ddd;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.phc-hashtags-box:last-of-type{
 margin-right: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px){
 .phc-hashtags-box{
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 1%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
 .phc-hashtags-box{
  width: 29.6%;
  margin-right: 1%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
 .phc-hashtags-box{
  width: 27.5%;
  margin-right: 1%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){
 .phc-hashtags-box{
  width: 94%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
 }
 .phc-home-hashtags-section-content{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 359px){
 .phc-hashtags-box{
  width: 92%;
 }
}
.phc-hashtags-box:hover{
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0px #aaa;
}
.phc-hashtags-box-title{
 color: #666;
 padding: 0px 5px 5px;
}
.phc-hashtags-box-tags{
 color: #666;
 font-size: 14px;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 padding: 3px 10px;
}
.phc-hashtags-box-tags-copied{
 background-color: #d4d4d4;
}
.phc-hashtags-box-button{
 position:relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #3f51b5;
 color: #fff;
 padding:5px 10px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 8px;
 float: right;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
.phc-hashtags-box-button:hover{
 background-color: #009688;
}
.phc-hashtags-box-button-clicked{
 background-color: #009688;
}


/***toast***/
#phc-toast {
    visibility: hidden;
    max-width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    /*margin-left: -125px;*/
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;right:0;
    bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#phc-toast #img{
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #009688;
    color: #fff;
}
#phc-toast #phc-toast-message{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
    padding: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
#phc-toast.show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, expand 0.5s 0.5s,stay 3s 1s, shrink 0.5s 2s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
    animation: fadein 0.5s, expand 0.5s 0.5s,stay 3s 1s, shrink 0.5s 4s, fadeout 0.5s 4.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;} 
    to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
    to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes expand {
    from {min-width: 50px} 
    to {min-width: 200px}
}
@keyframes expand {
    from {min-width: 50px}
    to {min-width: 200px}
}
@-webkit-keyframes stay {
    from {min-width: 200px} 
    to {min-width: 200px}
}
@keyframes stay {
    from {min-width: 200px}
    to {min-width: 200px}
}
@-webkit-keyframes shrink {
    from {min-width: 200px;} 
    to {min-width: 50px;}
}
@keyframes shrink {
    from {min-width: 200px;} 
    to {min-width: 50px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;} 
    to {bottom: 60px; opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
    to {bottom: 60px; opacity: 0;}
}

/***scroll to top***/
#return-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background: #e91e63;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
    -moz-border-radius: 35px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
#return-to-top img{
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 16px;
    top: 13px;
 width: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
#return-to-top:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0px #aaa;
}
#return-to-top:hover img {
    top: 6px;
}


/***scrollbar***/
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    height: 10px;
}
/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 background: #111;
}
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #009688; 
    border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #057d72; 
}

/***text selection color***/
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
    color: #fff;
    background: #e91e63;
}
::selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: #e91e63;
}
footer{
 background-color: #fff;
 height: 150px;
 
}
.phc-copyright{
 color: #666;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 150px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  
  
  <div class="phc-home-fold-content">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="phc-home-intro">
     <h1 class="phc-home-intro-title"><img class="phc-brand-home-intro" src="assets/img/phc_logo.png">Search</h1>
     <form class="phc-home-search-container">
      <input type="text" id="phc-home-search-bar" placeholder="Search here...">
      <a href="#"><img class="phc-home-search-icon" src="assets/img/phc_search_icon.png"></a>
      <p class="phc-home-search-hashtag"></p>
     </form>
     
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <!--hashtags-->
  <div class="phc-home-hashtags">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="phc-home-hashtags-section">
     <div class="phc-home-hashtags-section-content">
      <div class="phc-hashtags-box">
       <h3 class="phc-hashtags-box-title">Box1</h3>
       <button onclick="launch_toast()" class="phc-hashtags-box-button">Copy</button>
       <p class="phc-hashtags-box-tags">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a scrambled it to make</p>
      </div>
      <div class="phc-hashtags-box">
       <h3 class="phc-hashtags-box-title">Box2</h3>
       <button onclick="launch_toast()" class="phc-hashtags-box-button">Copy</button>
       <p class="phc-hashtags-box-tags">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="phc-hashtags-box">
       <h3 class="phc-hashtags-box-title">Box3</h3>
       <button onclick="launch_toast()" class="phc-hashtags-box-button">Copy</button>
       <p class="phc-hashtags-box-tags">opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--toast message-->
    <div id="phc-toast">
     <div id="img"><img src="assets/img/phc_tick.png"></div>
     <div id="phc-toast-message">Copied!</div>
    </div><!--/toast message-->
    
    <!---scroll to top-->
    <a href="javascript:" id="return-to-top"><img src="assets/img/phc_scroll_to_top.png"></i></a>
    
   </div><!--/container-->
  </div><!--/hashtags-->
  
  
  <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are filtering all elements inside `$('.phc-home-hashtags')` when using `$(".phc-home-hashtags *").filter`. So `$(this).toggle` will keep only the exact element that matches the filter text.

You need to filter only upon the `.phc-hashtags-box` boxes and their contents, change your filter like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#phc-home-search-bar").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".phc-home-hashtags .phc-hashtags-box").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
//finding and copying tags
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.phc-hashtags-box-button', function () {
  var copy = $(this).parents('.phc-hashtags-box').find('.phc-hashtags-box-tags').html();
  console.log(copy);
  var $temp = $('<input>');
  $('body').append($temp);
  $temp.val(copy).select();
  console.log($temp);
  document.execCommand('copy');
  $temp.remove();
    });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#phc-home-search-bar").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".phc-home-hashtags .phc-hashtags-box").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});


//toast message
function launch_toast() {
    var x = document.getElementById("phc-toast")
    x.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 5000);
}

//scroll to top 
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 150) {        // If page is scrolled more than 50px
        $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(400);    // Fade in the arrow
    } else {
        $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(400);   // Else fade out the arrow
    }
});
$('#return-to-top').click(function() {      // When arrow is clicked
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop : 0                       // Scroll to top of body
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
/***1. css reset***/
body{
 font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 margin:0;
 line-height:1.6;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 font-weight: 400;
}

/***2. container***/
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}

/***3. header***/
header{
 background-color: #fff;
 height: 80px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 1px #d8d8d8;
}
.phc-brand{
 float: left;
}
.phc-brand-logo{
 width: 40px;
 margin: 20px 0px;
}
.phc-navigation{
 float: right;
 line-height: 40px;
}
.phc-navigation-item{
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
 color: #888;
 margin-right: 40px;
}
.phc-navigation-item:last-of-type{
 margin-right: 0;
}
.phc-navigation-item a{
 color: #888;
 text-decoration: none;
}
/***4. home-intro***/
.phc-home-fold-content{
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 padding: 50px 0px 20px;
}

.phc-home-intro{
 text-align: center;
}
.phc-home-intro-title{
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.phc-brand-home-intro{
 width: 24px;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
.phc-home-search-container{
 width: 580px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
#phc-home-search-bar{
 width: 100%;
 outline: none;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
 box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
 height: 50px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 5px 38px;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #888;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ddd;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
#phc-home-search-bar:focus{
 color: #666;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0px #aaa;
}
.phc-home-search-icon{
 padding: 12px;
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 top: -48px;
 right: 0px;
 opacity: 0.4;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
 .phc-home-intro-title{
  line-height: 1.2;
 }
 .phc-home-search-container{
  width: 100%;
 }
}
.phc-home-search-hashtag{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 top: -43px;
 left: 15px;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #666;
}
.phc-home-intro-tip{
 color: #999;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}


/***hashtags-box-tags***/
.phc-home-hashtags{
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 padding: 40px 0px;
}
.phc-home-hashtags-section{
 display: inline-block;
}
.phc-home-hashtags-section-title{
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #3f51b5;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 5px 12px;
 display: table-cell;
}
.phc-home-hashtags-section-content{
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom:15px;
}
.phc-hashtags-box{
 display:inline-block;
 width: 30.5%;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-right: 1.3%;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ddd;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.phc-hashtags-box:last-of-type{
 margin-right: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px){
 .phc-hashtags-box{
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 1%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
 .phc-hashtags-box{
  width: 29.6%;
  margin-right: 1%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
 .phc-hashtags-box{
  width: 27.5%;
  margin-right: 1%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){
 .phc-hashtags-box{
  width: 94%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
 }
 .phc-home-hashtags-section-content{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 359px){
 .phc-hashtags-box{
  width: 92%;
 }
}
.phc-hashtags-box:hover{
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0px #aaa;
}
.phc-hashtags-box-title{
 color: #666;
 padding: 0px 5px 5px;
}
.phc-hashtags-box-tags{
 color: #666;
 font-size: 14px;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 padding: 3px 10px;
}
.phc-hashtags-box-tags-copied{
 background-color: #d4d4d4;
}
.phc-hashtags-box-button{
 position:relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #3f51b5;
 color: #fff;
 padding:5px 10px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 8px;
 float: right;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
.phc-hashtags-box-button:hover{
 background-color: #009688;
}
.phc-hashtags-box-button-clicked{
 background-color: #009688;
}


/***toast***/
#phc-toast {
    visibility: hidden;
    max-width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    /*margin-left: -125px;*/
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;right:0;
    bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#phc-toast #img{
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #009688;
    color: #fff;
}
#phc-toast #phc-toast-message{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
    padding: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
#phc-toast.show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, expand 0.5s 0.5s,stay 3s 1s, shrink 0.5s 2s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
    animation: fadein 0.5s, expand 0.5s 0.5s,stay 3s 1s, shrink 0.5s 4s, fadeout 0.5s 4.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;} 
    to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
    to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes expand {
    from {min-width: 50px} 
    to {min-width: 200px}
}
@keyframes expand {
    from {min-width: 50px}
    to {min-width: 200px}
}
@-webkit-keyframes stay {
    from {min-width: 200px} 
    to {min-width: 200px}
}
@keyframes stay {
    from {min-width: 200px}
    to {min-width: 200px}
}
@-webkit-keyframes shrink {
    from {min-width: 200px;} 
    to {min-width: 50px;}
}
@keyframes shrink {
    from {min-width: 200px;} 
    to {min-width: 50px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;} 
    to {bottom: 60px; opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
    to {bottom: 60px; opacity: 0;}
}

/***scroll to top***/
#return-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background: #e91e63;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
    -moz-border-radius: 35px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
#return-to-top img{
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 16px;
    top: 13px;
 width: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
#return-to-top:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0px #aaa;
}
#return-to-top:hover img {
    top: 6px;
}


/***scrollbar***/
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    height: 10px;
}
/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 background: #111;
}
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #009688; 
    border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #057d72; 
}

/***text selection color***/
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
    color: #fff;
    background: #e91e63;
}
::selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: #e91e63;
}
footer{
 background-color: #fff;
 height: 150px;
 
}
.phc-copyright{
 color: #666;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 150px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  
  
  <div class="phc-home-fold-content">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="phc-home-intro">
     <h1 class="phc-home-intro-title"><img class="phc-brand-home-intro" src="assets/img/phc_logo.png">Search</h1>
     <form class="phc-home-search-container">
      <input type="text" id="phc-home-search-bar" placeholder="Search here...">
      <a href="#"><img class="phc-home-search-icon" src="assets/img/phc_search_icon.png"></a>
      <p class="phc-home-search-hashtag"></p>
     </form>
     
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <!--hashtags-->
  <div class="phc-home-hashtags">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="phc-home-hashtags-section">
     <div class="phc-home-hashtags-section-content">
      <div class="phc-hashtags-box">
       <h3 class="phc-hashtags-box-title">Box1</h3>
       <button onclick="launch_toast()" class="phc-hashtags-box-button">Copy</button>
       <p class="phc-hashtags-box-tags">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a scrambled it to make</p>
      </div>
      <div class="phc-hashtags-box">
       <h3 class="phc-hashtags-box-title">Box2</h3>
       <button onclick="launch_toast()" class="phc-hashtags-box-button">Copy</button>
       <p class="phc-hashtags-box-tags">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="phc-hashtags-box">
       <h3 class="phc-hashtags-box-title">Box3</h3>
       <button onclick="launch_toast()" class="phc-hashtags-box-button">Copy</button>
       <p class="phc-hashtags-box-tags">opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--toast message-->
    <div id="phc-toast">
     <div id="img"><img src="assets/img/phc_tick.png"></div>
     <div id="phc-toast-message">Copied!</div>
    </div><!--/toast message-->
    
    <!---scroll to top-->
    <a href="javascript:" id="return-to-top"><img src="assets/img/phc_scroll_to_top.png"></i></a>
    
   </div><!--/container-->
  </div><!--/hashtags-->
  
  
  <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, yes. I thought it won't look for the words inside the card. So I used filter all. Thanks mate.